# How to replace value in string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

How to remove my value in String Array and how i can rearrange

```
public string[] selNames = new string[5];
selNames[0]="AA";
selNames[1]="BB";
selNames[2]="CC";
selNames[3]="DD";
selNames[4]="EE";
```

In certain Conditaion i need to Check for the existing value and i want to remove it from my collection, How i can do it.

i tried like below, but i cannot, it returns true, but how to make that index value to null

> ```
> If(selNames .Contains("CC").ToString()==true)
> ```
>
> {
>   //  how to make that index null which contains the "CC"; and i need to rearrage the array
>   }

Comment: Can you use another data structure instead of array, e.g. Dictionary<> http://bit.ly/9IhY4j or HashSet<> http://bit.ly/c4GMUu? It provides both features (quick search and removing) by default.

Comment: @ Nick Martyshchenko :(+1) i think `Generic` types are more flexible to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the '**List< T >**' for checking the existing values and also can remove the item from the list and also can arrange the list.
The following is the code snippet:

```
 List<string> list = new List<string>();
 list.Add("AA");
 list.Add("BB");
 list.Add("CC");
 list.Add("DD");
 list.Add("EE");
 list.Add("FF");
 list.Add("GG");
 list.Add("HH");
 list.Add("II");

 MessageBox.Show(list.Count.ToString());
 list.Remove("CC");
 MessageBox.Show(list.Count.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do following.

```
var newArray = selNames.Where(s => s != "CC").ToArray();
```

where s is the arg of the `Func<TSource, bool>` delegate TSource is string in your case.
So it will compare each string in array and return all which is not "СС"

here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) to msdn

Comment: Wouldn't this be enough? var newArray = selNames.Where(s => s != "CC").ToArray();

Comment: @deep : `s` represents the current item in the array. just like X in `foreach(String X in selNames )`